# unittest save button click in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python unit testing. i am searching for a best way to unit test a save button click. the save button click function takes two arguments, one is an instance and other is a list of instances. i want to unit test the save button click by comparing the data passed as argument and the data retrieved from the database after the save button is clicked. Can anybody help me to find out the best unit test method for testing my save button click

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Are you saying that you want to unit test your database connection? Or the relation between the button and the save command?

Comment: It sounds like you've got an idea that should work (compare the data passed as an argument to the data retrieved from the database after the button is clicked). If there's some more complicated issue with doing that, it would help to see some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

python has a built-in unittest module.

http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

Comment: OP provides no code, and i have no way to simply comment on his post at the moment, still i try to help him, he wants to unittest something in python. it has a built-in. i hope it helps him. and i wish i had some code i could try to fix for him.. but i do not.

Comment: Thank you friends for your replays.. mean while i figured something that solved my problem, i don't say that its optimized but i solved my problem with the help of a method. Actually what i wanted is to test that the data passed through the save button is successfully saved in the database. That is the instance, and list of instances that passed through the function must be the same that is retrieved  after the save button click.

Comment: So i first took those arguments(instance and list of instances) into two temporary variables and called the save button and then i retrieved those data into another variables(instance variable and list of instance variable). then i created a method that take an instance as argument and return a list that contain the attributes of that instances, and compared those instances before save button click and after save button click ( assertEqual() ). Though this is not an effective way to test. but it works. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: in the interest of this site could you post your code as an answer so that others can learn from this?